How robust are the solutions to Socialist Millionaires?
In the socialist millionaire's problem, Alice and Bob, owning respectively values $a$ and $b$, want to check if $a=b$ by communicating publicly. At the end of the exchange between them, Alice and Bob should know whether $a=b$ without disclosing any information about $a$ and $b$.
Wikipedia then says

Even if one of the parties is dishonest and deviates from the protocol, that person cannot learn anything more than if $x=y$. An active attacker capable of arbitrarily interfering with Alice and Bob's communication (man-in-the-middle attack) cannot learn more than a passive attacker and cannot affect the outcome of the protocol other than to make it fail.

Suppose that a solution exists to this problem. Then, if Alice can check whether $a=b$ after having followed the protocol and having created some amount of secret keys, then so can anyone who knows $a$ and the set of secret keys created by Alice. So I guess that if Alice were really corrupted, she could publish all her private keys together with $a$ and the truth/falsity of $a=b$ would be publicly known.
My question: is this protocol supposed to be robust against this attack (i.e. am I missing something)?

I don't think anyone can stop Alice by sharing a secret information she posses.
I suppose its the same case as in an encryption scheme, if Bob sent a secret message to Alice and Alice shared it to the world, by exposing her secret key and showing her decryption computation.
But, your attack doesn't contradict what Wikipedia claims.
The secrecy provided by the protocol that Wikipedia states is that:

Even if Alice deviates from the protocol (by saying "lies", asking maliciously crafted answers), she won't be able to obtain anything else than if $a=b$ (e.g. also get the secret key of Bob)
Eve that is watching Alice and Bob communicating can't trick them into believing that $a=b$ while this doesn't hold. She can just make them unable to complete the protocol.

EDIT: Your attack reminds me of coercion-resistance, a security property of electronic-voting protocols that forbids the signer to be able to prove what they have voted (in order to not allow vote selling). However, I don't know much/how something like that could be adapted here. Basically, Alice should not be able to prove that her computations were actually valid.

Typically Alice can publish everything and then people would know.
However, there is a notion called deniable encryption https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deniable_encryption. So you could add this to the protocol to prevent Alice from being able to claim you said something.
Here's a talk on deniable mpc https://ntt-research.com/cis-ran-canetti-2020summit-summary/ I'm sure there are references there in.
